# Emulating Android Drone Control App On Windows

Tags: java, android, ios, packet-capture, decompiler

I recently purchased a Yuneec Breeze quad-copter drone that uses an Android and iOS app with its own WiFi connection as a controller.

I am looking to write a Java application that performs the functions of the Android app with Game Controller support (the Breeze Cam app uses the touchscreen which means my big thumbs cover the streaming video) but am running into a roadblock.

While being proficient in Java, including network functions, I find myself woefully uninformed as to how to capture and read the network traffic between my phone and my drone.  Its simply a skill I never needed until now.

Any place to help me get started?

- OR -

Since I'm writing this in Java would de-compiling and hacking away at the Android source be a more viable option?

If so what decompilers are recommended?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience these apps tend to be written in proprietary code. Android may be an open-source project, but the apps written for it don't have to be. It's unlikely you'll be able to write your own code to control the drone unless Yuneec provides an API/SDK to do so.

A quick Google search yields this thread on their forums: https://yuneecpilots.com/threads/api-sdk.745/

It's not much info, but it looks like you're SOL. Sorry.

Comment: I've read that thread.  That's for a much more complex drone (the Typhoon) and based on the "quality" of Yuneec apps (and firmware updates) I doubt that the network traffic or app are very sophisticated.  

Some of Yuneec's drones can have the video feed captured live on a Windows PC using a web browser and simple requests.

Like I said I doubt they're doing anything sophisticated.  This company seems more of a quick-and-dirty-and-make-it-look-pretty than putting in any type of encryption.

And if its Android app its been done in Java so re-creating their work should not be difficult.